# Feeds are showing where Post archive page should be

Tags: theme-development, podcasting

**The problem:**
Archive/category page is showing up as a feed.
https:// site-example.com/show/ shows a feed instead of posts.

**Details:**
Updated WordPress to 4.8.
Everything else is updated.
The links must stay the same.
There is a feed with the same title at:
--  https:// site-example.com/feed/show/
Using wp-forge theme with a child theme.

**What I've tried:**
Created a template with various names as [per the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates).
Disabled and removed all plugins and themes.
Deleted and removed cache plugins.
Disabled all feeds.. those 2 are still showing up.(/feed/show and /show)

I'm sure someone will have an answer already for this.
It can't be a new issue... I'm just new to feed management.
Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for various solutions I have come up with an alternate solution that has solved my issue.
I simply removed the /%category%/ base from the permalinks and installed the "No Category Base (WPML)" plugin and WordPress found my category template and is now showing all the posts from the "Show" category as an archive. :)